# How to return resonse from ajax and display it in Blade file in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to integrate sorting system in laravel application, I am able to do ajax call and got the response but how to display that data in blade file.

I have the data already displayed on search page now if user try to sort the and old data will replaced by the new data.

How can I do that.

Controller Code :

```
public function sort_data(Request $request){
    $results='';
    if(request()->sub_sub_category){
        $results = Product::orderBy($request->sorting_selection,'asc')->with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
            $query->where('slug', request()->sub_sub_category);
        })->paginate(24);
    } elseif (request()->sub_category){
        $results = Product::orderBy($request->sorting_selection,'asc')->with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
            $query->where('slug', request()->sub_category);
        })->paginate(24);
    } elseif (request()->category){
        $results = Product::orderBy($request->sorting_selection,'asc')->with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query){
            $query->where('slug', request()->category);
        })->paginate(24);
    } else{
        $results = Product::orderBy($request->sorting_selection,'asc')->with('categories')->paginate(24);
    }
//        $returnHTML = view('pages.user.shop.products.products')->with(["products"=>$results])->render();
//        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
//        return response()->json(['products' => $results, 'status' => 200]);
        return view('pages.user.shop.products.products')->with(["products"=>$results]);
    }
```

I have already tried the commented code. But not success

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#soting-select').on('change', function(){
        var value = document.getElementById('soting-select').value;
        var ajaxurl = '/sort-product';
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'sorting_selection' : value
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Old Response :
[image]

New Response :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$results->toJson()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `render()` on the `view`.
And also you may need to change the `$results` variable to `$products` as you have shared the data with `$products` variable in your blade file.

```
$returnHTML = view('pages.user.shop.products.products', compact('products'))->render();
```

See the [`View`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L88) source code for more information.

Comment: Op tagged with `laravel-8`, might want to update that link

Comment: View not updated, Got the result but how to update the view?

Comment: I am using laravel-8 @brombeer

Comment: @Pooja That's what I said, Urja's "View" link is for Laravel5.6 - things might have changed (a lot) between those versions, that's why I asked to update the link to Laravel8

Comment: ok, Misunderstood that comment @brombeer

Comment: @Pooja Sorry, don't understand you, `Got the result but how to update the view?` means ?

Comment: when I click on sort by name, then a request goes to controller and controller give the result, that is on $product variable, after that  

$returnHTML = view('pages.user.shop.products.products', compact('products'))->render();

But, My view is still the same. nothing's chnaged,

Previous result was like B, A

After sorting new  result is like B, A

Comment: Ok, Can you make sure that the variable define is used correctly and there is no error in ajax response ..

Comment: Question updated, check the image plz @UrjaSatodiya

Comment: Please check your console log, and also check in `Network` tab with `Xhr` option what response you got from the ajax call

Comment: @Pooja You'd need your javascript to change the view in your `success` function. (Rendering the same view via AJAX makes kind of little sense though, this could've been done with a "regular" GET request.)